# username and password passed as integers rather than strings

Tags: php, post

I'm creating a login script and its failing each time even when I input the correct credentials. I firstly thought this was to do with the crypt function which has been explained in depth and have done further research upon to find a good method.

Anyway I have remove the crypt function in both the login and register to test the login script. Upon removing this I still got an error which stated `Invalid username or password`.

I wanted to see what was actually been passed in my `POST` variables, so I echoed these variables as they are defined e.g.

`$username = isset($_POST['username']);`

`echo $username;`

outputs: `1`

however

`echo $_POST['username'];`

outputs `admin` (which is the username I have been using)

If I remove the isset from this POST variable then I am returned with the true value but this still fails my login script.

I don't understand whats going wrong as I've used this same statement in a different function to test it and it works, instead of using POST variables I am already setting the username and password and then wrapping in a foreach statement and this works.

It must be something to do with my POST variables and the way I am handling it but I don't have the experience/knowledge to solve the problem. I can't understand why my POST data is returned as a integer but then even when I remove the isset tag my statement is still false?

Any input and help is greatly welcomed and appreciated.

Below is my code, if there's anything else required please ask:

index.php

```
<form id="loginForm" method="POST" action="classes/class.Login.php">
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="showpassword"/> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in"/>
```

classes/class.Login.php

```
public function loginuser() {

        $username = isset($_POST['username']);
        $password = isset($_POST['password']);

        //$salt = "boo";
        //$pw = crypt($password, $salt);

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bindValue(":username", $_POST['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(":password", $_POST['password'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

            if ($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
                    $_SESSION['authorized'] = true;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    header('Location: testloginrequired.php');
                } else {
                    echo "Invaild username or password. Try again";                             
                }
    }// end loginuser
```

Comment: You are assigning the return value of isset to the variable thus the 1 value. You should use $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $username = $_POST['username'] : "";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
 $username = isset($_POST['username']);
```

to :

```
    $username =  ($_POST['username']);
```

`isset` function returns a boolean value (true,false) , so your `$username` would be boolean (true or `1`)  not a string!

Comment: ahh ok thanks I understand. right at least now I am passing my data through correctly now just need to work out why my statement is returning as false. will accept answer after S/O timeout :) thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
$username = isset($_POST['username']);
```

Is just checking if the variable is set. Get rid of the isset and change it simply to

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
```

If that doesn't work, then do this

```
$username = settype($username, "string");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use construction:

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) $username = $_POST['username'];
```

If you will remove "isset" check, you will get warning, if key 'username' will not exists in POST.

Improvement of your code:

```
$username = (isset($_POST['username'])) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
```

This is [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) and it's suitable in your case. If key 'username' exists in POST, then $username will equals $_POST['username'], otherwise $username will empty. Enjoy :)

Comment: thanks, I've used this method for my insert script but actually did not know what this meant but thanks for the explanation

Comment: Try to read manual. Actually it's very simple construction. I'll try to explain:


1. In parenthesis - isset($_POST['username']): we check existence 'username' key in global POST-request.


2. Then, if this key exists, we read value from POST-request and assign to $username variable.


3. If no, we assign empty value to $username variable. This step is need for further processing of $username.